# How to turn off caching when testing Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm stress testing Elastic Search by sending queries but am afraid the responses are being cached.  How do I turn off caching when testing Elastic Search?

Comment: Caching is an important part of elasticsearch, I do not think complete REST responses are cached though. So turning of caching to test performance does not sound logical. You probably want to test current users? How big is your dataset? What kind of queries? What setup of elasticsearch? A lof of questions and a lot of parts that influence performance. So maybe you can elaborate a bit more about what you want to test?

Comment: I had a test that sent 100,000 requests per min, with the query "cars".  I figured "cars" was probably cached after the first search, and that this was not going to help me test production, where the query would be different every time.  I thought maybe I could query for a different word from the the english dictionary on every search...OR just turn off caching instead.  What do you think?

Comment: I'm trying to find the point where errors are returned or response time slows to above 200ms.  I found that 100,000 a min with 300 concurrent connections was my breaking point, with an error message about Elastic Searche's queue being full.  But this is with the caching that I'm assuming is going on.

Comment: You cannot really turn of caching and it will not give you the right answer. The alternative of having more queries is a lot better. It also depends a lot on the content. How many different terms do you have, what other things are you doing. Using aggregations a lot? And of course the amount of memory available to elasticsearch, the OS, the number of nodes. So many influences.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Before I answer, a disclaimer that I agree with the comments on the question, disabling cache is not the best way to stress test Elasticsearch. Hitting it with simultaneous queries that are representative of your production query set along with active indexing at the same time is going to be a far better way to see how ES responds under load.

However, to answer your question and point out some caveats:

1. You can clear your cache in between runs:

   > The clear cache API allows to clear either all caches or specific
   >   cached associated with one ore more indices.

   https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-clearcache.html
2. You can turn off your filter cache by setting
   index.cache.filter.type to none - this will prevent filter results
   from being cached:

   http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Disable-cache-td3825105.html

   http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Disabling-cache-td3201850.html
3. You can change the settings for the field data cache - however I
   don't know what will happen if you set this to zero:

   https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-fielddata.html
4. Overall, though, keep in mind that Elasticsearch makes significant
   use of the native OS filesystem cache, so much of "caching" is
   happening outside the control of ES:

   https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/05/elasticsearch-indexing-performance-cheatsheet/

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'm taking the advice of using queries that are closer to what is searched for in production. I downloaded a dump of the english dictionary and use a different word for each test query.

Comment: Good plan, I agree that's a superior approach. If my answer addressed your original question could you go ahead and accept it?

Answer (score 22):

```
GET /my_index/_search?request_cache=false
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/shard-request-cache.html